# What would cause Firefox to display PDFs with only diacritic text and symbols?

Tags: firefox, pdf, fonts

I'm running into an issue where Firefox is showing some PDFs downloaded from a certain website with all foreign language/diacritic fonts and symbols.

[image: Example]

When the file is downloaded and opened in other applications (or other instances of Firefox on other computers), it displays perfectly fine. The document does not show any issues when opened in Chrome or Edge.

Firefox on this PC was reinstalled, and I also tried setting security.sandbox.content.level to zero and restarting. The developer mode console doesn't show any relevant errors and upon inspection, the font of that selection is "sans-serif" which I'd think would be generic enough to avoid any font-specific issues on the host.

Any ideas on what else I can try to resolve this?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a new test user and installing FFox on that PC? That would differentiate between OS and user issues. [Yes, it's a bit of extra work.]

Comment: No, but that's a great idea. I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: If the idea doesn't work out, please give us a link to an example file.

Comment: @KJ, That is not the Op's question. "[In] other instances of Firefox on other computers, it displays perfectly fine." The question concerns Firefox why works on this PDF on **all other** PC's but not this.

Comment: All, I cannot provide a sample unfortunately since the document in question contains sensitive banking information. If the screenshot is insufficient to diagnose the issue I may just contact the bank and see what they can tell me. I was hoping it was some sort of garden-variety browser issue but it sounds like that may not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was ultimately able to resolve the issue by changing the about:config setting "browser.display.use_document_fonts" from 1 to 0.